# zsh: killed python3 on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: python, python-3.x, zsh, apple-m1

I'm trying to run Python 3 on the new M1 chip MacBook. I tried installing python3 both via the official Python website (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-391/) and also via `brew install python3`. Both of the installations succeeded, however when I try running the command `python3` in Terminal I get this error:

```
zsh: killed     python3
```

Does anyone know what's going on? I couldn't find anything online and I think my installation should be fine. I did have to change my ~/.zshrc file for a class, but I'm not sure if that's the issue?

Comment: Have you checked the bugtracking system? "change my ~/.zshrc file for a class" -- if you're wondering whether that's the issue, there's a very simple way to find out, just revert the changes.

Comment: @JunlinYi : I hope that you did not blindly change your .zshrc without knowing what you are doing, but if you suspect that this could be the reason, try to run Python via `zsh --fc python3`, or from a _bash_ login shell; is it still killed? Also, investigate what `file $(whence -c python3)` outputs.

Answer (score 9):

I faced this same issue in the M1 Macbook pro and fixed it by doing the following

Open `~/.zshrc` file (Create a new one if not present already)
Add the following line

```
alias python3="/usr/bin/python3"
```

Make sure you are able to access python3 from the above location by running

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

This should invoke Python3 for you or check for the correct path in `/usr/bin` and update the above line accordingly. You can do the same for other versions of Python also accordingly.

Comment: What is the actual issue, and why does this fix it?

Answer (score 8):

For others who might have the same root cause:
Mine had nothing to do with my Python installation, it was caused by a bad merge in Pandas (accidently creating a dataframe with 22 Billion rows, it was trying to allocate 33GB of memory).

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling python and all dependencies using homebrew!

```
brew reinstall $(brew deps python3) python3
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and it was resolved by an ol' fashioned computer restart!

I suspect a mem leak but I'm not sure. I would have then tried reinstalling Python but it ended up not being necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I started to face the same issue myself while on M1 chip MacBook with macOS Monterey. I was using VS code to try to run my python script and it worked fine. But when I tried it on the terminal I kept getting that same response.

The simple solution that I found to work was specifying which python version I was running. Ex: say I have a file named testing.py and I am running the latest version of python 3.X, then in my terminal I would do

```
python3.X testing.py
```

and everything seemed to run just fine (at least for me).

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Python data analysis package attempted to cross pc memory limit.
After I decrease the computational matrix the program run ok!

Answer (score -1):

I got a same error. Then I disabled MacOS System Integrity Protection(SIP), python3 runs correctly.