# zsh: killed python3 on M1 Pro MacBook Pro

Tags: python, terminal, path, zsh

hello I've ran into a problem with running python3 on M1 MacBook pro. I deleted a version of python, after that I checked what version I was running and I get "zsh: killed     python3". python 3.9 is running on one of my projects in vscode, but it sort of bugs me that this error exists in terminal. Just looked around on this platform and found that I should try making a "~/.zshrc" file and run "alias python3="/usr/bin/python3" but I'm not sure that I did it correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [zsh: killed python3 on M1 MacBook Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66295155/zsh-killed-python3-on-m1-macbook-pro)