# During object detection with the YOLOv8 model, a 'zsh: killed' error occurs

Tags: python-3.x, yolo, yolov8

[image: yolov8 detection error]

First, since I am a foreigner, I used a translator to post my question, so I would like to ask for your understanding for any awkward sentences.

The execution environment is vscode on macbook m1.

When object detection is performed on an mp4 video using YOLOv8, a situation like the picture occurs.

The photo is detected normally, but the video ends like this during detection.

[zsh: killed python3 on M1 MacBook Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66295155/zsh-killed-python3-on-m1-macbook-pro)

[image: Before changing ~/.zshrc]
[image: After changing ~/.zshrc]

I changed my ~/.zshrc file by referring to the Stackoverflow Q&A above, but the error continues to occur.

The second picture is before changing ~/.zshrc and the third picture is after changing it.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me a solution to this problem.

Comment: I suggest it may be an out-of-memory problem, as the inference process crashes by the end of a video file. Direct `model.predict()`  process accumulates all source inference results in RAM, causing potential out-of-memory errors for large files or long-running streams and videos. Try to run a video inference with the `stream=True` argument, it returns a memory-efficient result generator instead of a full results list. Usage example is here: https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#key-features-of-predict-mode.

Comment: Example of a per-frame video inference with opencv: https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#streaming-source-for-loop

Comment: When I checked the activation status, it turned out to be a problem with insufficient memory. I solved the problem using the 'stream=True' function you mentioned and got the result. Thank you very much for your reply.